# What's the opposite of "from the outside"?

Tags: phrase-requests

There are two ways of describing something: from the outside (how external entities engage with it), and _ _ _ (how it actually works). What's a phrase that could go in the blank, meaning "in the inside"?

Comment: Why not "from the inside"?

Comment: "Vice versa", "from the inside out", "the reverse".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the word "internally" should do just fine.

wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=internally